# Drools how to get object which the rule executed?

Tags: drools

I have following specific requirement to be implemented in Drools. Don't know how to do this. If anyone know give me a direction.

In my project drool rules are associated into a java class . Rules are defined as string list filed in the class. I have list of these class objects and I need to execute rules of these classes. I used following code to add rules. Imagine "Test" class has the rules.

```
for (Test test : testList) {
                List<String> rules = test.getRules();
                if (rules != null) {
                    for (String rule : rules) {
                        System.out.println("Added Rule...");
                        knowledgeBuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(rule.getBytes()), ResourceType.DRL);
                    }
                }
            }
```

as facts "Test" object list and other required objects are added. Rules are executing without an issue. Now i need to get specific "Test" object which the rule succeed. Does anybody have an idea how to do this ? I think there should be a mechanism to combine Test object with rule, but don't know how to do that. Can any one help ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the RHS of a rule there's a magic variable called `kcontext` (an instance of `RuleContext`), which supports `kcontext.getMatch().getObjects()`.

Or maybe you're looking for the iterator methods available on the Session interface, which iterate through all of the facts in the working memory?